# Magento PayPal Payment missing Shipping Fee...but only sometimes

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.4

A client has Magento  1.4.0.1 with Authorize.net and PayPal Standard. It's been working fine for 6 months.  Mid-June Magento starts sending some PayPal orders without the shipping fee. Some orders are fine, while others have it missing.  There doesn't seem to be anything linking the orders with the missing shipping fees. It seems Magento isn't sending the shipping fee or PayPal isn't receiving it correctly.  Anyone experience this or have a fix?

Comment: Which one is it, Magento not sending it or PayPal not retrieving it?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is slightly old, but here's [the answer and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411201/magento-1-4-paypal-payments-standard-sometimes-wont-charge-shipping/11434333#11434333). It is essentially a bug with this version of Magento specifically (1.4.0.1).

The link included is a page that describes what causes the problem and provides a zip file of modified files that can be used to replace some of your core files in the Magento install.